# Editing SQL code in multiple queries at one time

Tags: ms-access

I'd like to automate a procedure some. Basically, what I do is import a few spreadsheets from Excel, delete the old spreadsheets that I previously imported, and then change a few queries to reflect the title of the new imports. And then I change the name of the queries to reflect that I've changed them.

I suppose I could make this a bit easier by keeping the imported documents the same name as the old ones, so I'm open to doing that, but that still leaves changing the queries. That's not too difficult, either. The name stays pretty much the same, except the reports I'm working with are dated. I wish I could just do a "find and replace" in the SQL editor, but I don't think there's anything like that.

I'm open to forms, macros, or visual basic. Just about anything.

I've just been doing everything manually.

Comment: Third-party add-ins can do the Find/Replace or you can write you own code. I have used Rick Fishers Find and Replace and another option is V-Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I have correctly understood the setup, there are a few ways in which this could be automated, without the need to continually modify the SQL of the queries which operate on the imported spreadsheet.

Following the import, you could either execute an append query to transfer the data into a known pre-existing table (after deleting any existing data from the table), avoiding the need to modify any of your other queries. Alternatively, you could rename the name of the imported table.

The task is then reduced to identifying the name of the imported table, given that it will vary for each import.

If the name of the spreasheet follows logical rules (you mention that the sheets are dated), then perhaps you could calculate the anticipated name based on the date on which the import occurs.

Alternatively, you could store a list of the tables present in your database and then query this list for additions following the import to identify the name of the imported table.